# Configure Apache on Windows 7

Tags: apache

I want to test some code on localhost before uploading to a live site. So I decided to install Apache. I'm running 64bit windows 7 enterprise edition. I downloaded httpd-2.0.64-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi. I installed it under C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2
I have set domain name and server name to localhost in my installation, and used default value for all other steps. In my configuration file httpd.conf, I have ServerName localhost:80.

I followed everything I can find on online apache installation tutorials. But when I typed in localhost in my browser, I got a 404 error :(

I know it's very hard to diagnose this way, but I just wonder if someone can spot an important step I'm missing.

I'm feeling it could be something to do with my 64bit machine, and the long folder name Program Files (x86). But I have tried to install on C:\Apache directly and failed too (even got an error during installation). Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. Apache service didn't start because another system process was listening to port 80. Refer to these two posts for solutions:
http://forums.zpanelcp.com/archive/index.php/t-5265.html
http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=1575&title=Apache_won%27t_start
Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the service?

Also, you should install XAMPP or WAMPP, which offers Apache, PHP and MySQL support without all the configuration hassle.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a 404 error then either the webserver is running or you failed to start it *and* have something very wrong with the existing network config on your machine.

The latter is a lot more likely - and you can check this by looking at the logs which it has generated - there should be entries in both the access and error log.

If the problem is the spaces in the path (you'll see an error relating to the documentroot from the entries added to the error_log at startup) then (IIRC) you can either enclose the path in double quotes or use a path for the document root which doesn't have spaces - the content doesn't have to site below the directory you installed Apache into - indeed it's arguable that using a different path is good practice. Note that several versions of mod_fcgid don't like paths with spaces even if you quote them.